# mod_eventful contributed module not working with ejabberd from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am using an "ejabberd module that will turn events into HTTP requests" from the following Github repository: https://github.com/theozaurus/mod_eventful

Here mod_eventful working fine with ubuntu 12.04 but its not working when tried same with ubuntu 14.04

Is there any suggestion on why its not working and how to solve the issue ?

**What I did**

On following link all steps are mention very clearly : https://gist.github.com/jrvaja/6512c1fdf368930758f8

Comment: Do you have more details on the issue ? Is there any crash in ejabberd logs ?

Comment: How to check ejabberd logs ? and how to debug notification code ?

Comment: You should look for crash, error and suspicious messages in ejabberd.log and erlang.log or error.log depending on your configuration. The actual place of the files depend on how you did install ejabberd. You need to get yourself familiar with reading ejabberd log files as this is mandatory to develop ejabberd modules.